# Mongoose query ignore fields not in schema

Tags: mongoose

Here is my schema:

```
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  title: String,
  authorId: String,
})
```

I'd like to query it with:

```
Post.find({ authorId: '123', someField: 1 })
```

which results in `[]`, how can I make mongoose ignore query fields not in the schema?

Answer (score 2):

There is a flag `strictQuery` for it (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery)

> For backwards compatibility, the `strict` option does **not** apply to the `filter` parameter for queries. Mongoose has a separate `strictQuery` option to toggle strict mode for the `filter` parameter to queries.

```js
const mySchema = new Schema({ field: Number }, {
  strict: true,
  strictQuery: true // Turn on strict mode for query filters
});

const MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', mySchema);

// Mongoose will strip out `notInSchema: 1` because `strictQuery` is `true`
MyModel.find({ notInSchema: 1 });
```