# Querying for documents in mongodb is returning entire collection when I filter by one field, but works for all other fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is an odd one I'm experiencing.

I am trying to query a database of items for autocomplete. In order to make it easier for a user, I have a field on the item that is essentially just a string that combines the brand name and the item name, so an example document looks like:

```
{
  item: 'item name',
  brand: 'brand name',
  searchName: 'item name brand name',
}
```

This way, a user can search "Toyota Prius" or "Prius" or "Toyota" and the item will return.

However, for some reason, querying with a filter for item and brand works, however, querying on `searchName` just returns my entire collection. This problem only happens in my code though and does not happen in MongoDB Compass.

My query code is here:

```
    const itemsFromPSDB = await Item.find({
      searchName: userAutocompleteValue,
    })
      .lean()
      .limit(20);
    console.log(itemsFromPSDB);
```

If I for example, manually set:

```
userAutocompleteValue = 'test'
```

This will return my entire collection.

However, if I literally just change the field, resulting in the query looking like:

```
    console.log(regexToSearch);
    const itemsFromPSDB = await Item.find({
      item: userAutocompleteValue,
    })
      .lean()
      .limit(20);
    console.log(itemsFromPSDB);
```

It will only return values where the item is the value entered by a user.
It also works if I use literally any other field except for `searchName`

And I know for a fact `searchName` is the correct field because when I log `itemsFromPSDB` the result has the `searchName` field in it here is an actual code dump with some data obfuscated:

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("blahblah"),
    item: 'item name',
    brand: 'brand name',
    reviewCount: '2',
    reviewValue: '5.0',
    url: 'someUrl',
    imageUrl: 'someUrl',
    displayWeight: 342,
    unit: 'g',
    price: 275,
    description: '',
    techSpecs: [],
    category: 'category',
    searchName: 'item name brand name'
  }
```

One thing worth noting is that the field `searchName` was created by running a script that added the field to all documents. I'm not sure if that would matter though because the query works perfectly when I just run the query in the mongoDB compass gui.

I don't really know what to do short of dropping the whole database and reloading it. I'm considering doing that if I dont solve the problem soon, but Id like to know why this is happening in the first place. Its so weird to me that this works in MongoDB Compass but not in Nodejs.

edit: Here is the script I used to add searchName, in the same script I was also santizing some inputs as well, which all worked fine.

```
const items = await db.items.find();
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const { _id, price, displayWeight, brand, item, category } = items[i];
    console.log(`Updating ${item}`);
    const updated = await db.items.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id },
      {
        $set: {
          price:
            typeof price === String ? Number(price.replaceAll(",", "")) : price,
          displayWeight: Number(displayWeight),
          searchName: `${brand} ${item}`,
          category: category.toLowerCase(),
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(updated);
  }
```

Comment: Are you performing substring search like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3esY_X3QRiG) for the field `searchName`? It seems to me you are doing exact match currently.

Comment: And if the above does not solve your issue, sharing your script for populating the field `searchName` would be helpful. Your approach for using `searchName` as an auxiliary search field is sensible since the new field can be indexed and expedite the search. It might just be some minor issues that the field is incorrectly populated and causing unexpected search result.

Comment: I was actually doing that substring search initially, but it wasnt working. While debugging I tested to see if I could even query the field with an exact match and it wasn't working. So neither the substring regex query work, nor even exact query. However, both do work in Mongodb Compass.

I've added the script to the question that I used to set searchName. Just to reiterate, it does work fine in Mongodb compass, so not sure why its not working in my code when I literally just change the fieldname.

Comment: Does your `Item` model include the field `searchName`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276860/mongoose-query-ignore-fields-not-in-schema) might be related

Comment: Ah I literally just discovered that and came here to comment. That was indeed it. That explains why it doesn't work w/ Mongoose but does with MongoDB compass. Good find and thanks for the help. All is working well now.

Feel free to move that comment into an answer and Ill accept it as the answer. Thanks again for the help, truly appreciated.

Comment: Good to know that :) Sorry first but I think it might be better to mark this as a duplicate to that question :)