# Mongoose returning all records when using an invalid $exists find

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, exists

I have a MongoDB schema called `users` that has a very basic structure:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "631f0f3b40548b9388d96998",
        "email": "1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "_id": "6363ee3832abeb8da91c3bc0",
        "email": "2@email.com"
    }, ...
]
```

This works fine and I can query it using Mongoose with something like this to return a single record:

```
const users = await userModel.find({_id: "631f0f3b40548b9388d96998"})
```

However, I have a query that I use across my app that gets or'd with the find:

```
const users = await userModel.find({ $or: [{ _id: '631f0f3b40548b9388d96998' }, { sharedWith: { $exists: true } }] })
```

The problem is that `sharedWith` will never exist as it's not in the user schema (it is in the other schemas I use) and the query now returns every user as though it found a field called `sharedWith`, which is can't!

The find query works in a MongoDB shell and so appears to be a Mongoose issue?

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose query ignore fields not in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276860/mongoose-query-ignore-fields-not-in-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems it is not directly related to mongodb.

See this playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pbIgJoOGEM3